# What does "radio on ahead" mean in this context?

Tags: prepositions, adverbs

This context comes from the video game "*Bioshock*". Atlas is someone who communicated with the person speaking informing them about my upcoming visit and trying to arrange help for me.

*"Atlas radioed on ahead. Says you were looking for an invite to the fisheries. Nuts, I say. But, if'n you heads up to the wharf master's office and find ol' Peach a Research Camera, maybe I could manage an invite."*

There is no phrase such as "*on ahead*" and I'm short of ideas as to what the combination of "*on*" and "*ahead*" could mean. I assume this means that he "radioed before" I came to that location. **It would be great I someone provided definitions for both "*on*" and "*ahead*" in this context.**

Comment: "Atlas radioed [your request] on ahead": sent notice in advance by radio (before you arrived).

Comment: "On" and "ahead" aren't really combining here to form a phrasal meaning. He could have said "Atlas radioed ahead," meaning "ahead of your arrival" as you guess. Adding "on" is an idiomatic thing, similar to "come on" and "go on" and doesn't really add to the meaning; I'll see if someone can document it better in an answer.

Comment: The 'on' could be as in 'passed on your request'.

Comment: To perform a task *ahead* may mean earlier in time. **On ahead** helps clarify it's forward in distance (on the road ahead).

Comment: "Call ahead"/"phone ahead" are both common everyday phrases and don't seem to require "on". "Radio ahead" is significantly less common because most people don't have two-way radios. So maybe it feels necessary to include "on" to make the meaning clearer (alternatively you could clarify with something like "Atlas radioed ahead with a message").

Comment: From all of your answers, I concluded that "on" in this case means "further" as in "he passed the message on to the other department" & "ahead" means "in advance" as in  "We paid for the merch ahead of schedule". Can anyone confirm this as true?